# Tensorflow: Converting a tenor [B, T, S] to list of B tensors shaped [T, S]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

Tensorflow: Converting a tenor [B, T, S] to list of B tensors shaped [T, S]. Where B, T, S are whole positive numbers ...

How can I convert this? I can't do eval because no session is running at the time I want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want tf.unpack()

Comment: And it sounds like you know the exact answer I was looking for. :) thanks!